# I want to deploy the laravel web application into live?

Tags: laravel

I had developed the web application in laravel framework, now i need to deploy the application into live, for that how to build and deploy on windows server. please help me for this.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/deployment, but it's fairly unusual to put Laravel on a Windows box.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can deployed you app in a **Iaas** such as Digital Ocean but in Linux. Digital Ocean with LAMP [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-debian-8).  You will deploy in Linux but it is cheaper than a **Iaas** on windows.

If you can create a VM on VirtualBox, you will handle with Digital Ocean.